# Python create .txt with the information in json file

Tags: python, json, txt

Hihi guys, I'm new for python. Now I got a json file

```json
{
  "file_version": "1",
  "version_data": "4197",
  "panel_info": {
    "panel_barcode": "J Type:  GGA   Stype:  All",
    "board_barcode": [
      "NoSerialNumber"
    ],
    "inspection_time": "2021-08-24-20-07-10",
    "machine": "GGB",
    "model_name": "AIC",
  },
```

The json still have long list, I jus skip it.
And I want to read the json file and create a txt file with name (GGB[$]J Type[#]  GGA   Stype[#]  All[$]NoSerialNumber.txt), inside txt is empty.

I also want to loop because got a lot of these json file in each folder and hard to manual create 1 by 1.

This is my code(currently I just try to create one txt 1st)

```
import json

input_path = "C:\Data\Data1\AI.json"
output_path = "C:\index"

with open(input_path) as f:
  data = json.load(f)

  model_name = data['panel_info']['model_name']
  panel_barcode = data['panel_info']['panel_barcode']
  board_barcode = data['panel_info']['board_barcode']

  txt_name = model_name + '[$]' + panel_barcode + '[$]'
  f.close()

  output = open(output_path + '\\'+ (txt_name) + '.txt' , 'w')
  output.close()
```

Output

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\index\\GGB[$]J Type:  GGA   Stype:  All[$].txt'
```

Can help to check my code is correct or not and how to change the : symbol to [#] because window can't create name with :

Comment: Hi Yzj, what are you efforts? Have you tried to do it, yourself? Please put the code, that show what you've done..

Comment: You need to show some code at a minimum, please note SO is **not** a free code writing service.

Comment: Sorry. Just added my code but didn't know how to change the : to [#]

Answer (score 1):

> json.dump(json_data, open("file_name_of_choice", "w))